# Where to enter Facebook login authorized redirect URI?

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0

Where do I enter my Facebook app's authorized redirect URI? In the past this was under "PRODUCT SETTINGS" for "Facebook Login". Now the "PRODUCT SETTINGS" have changed to "Settings" and the field for the authorized redirect URI is gone. [image]

Answer (score 4):

In your `developers.facebook.com` dashboard for your app, look in the left column under `PRODUCTS` for `+ Add Product`. Click that and then click `Facebook Login`.

If you've already added `Facebook Login` then you'll see `Facebook Login` under `PRODUCTS`.

Now look down the page for `Valid OAuth redirect URIs`:[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you!! I spent almost 3 days looking for this piece of crap!! Redonkulus haha! Frustrated to no end, I couldn't even get started programming I was looking for a form input field! lol

Comment: As if OAuth isn't hard enough, Facebook's designers have to make it harder.